# How to run pry on Debian Linux for ARM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, pry, raspberry-pi

I installed rvm and Ruby 1.9.3p194 on a Raspberry Pi using Debian Linux.  When I installed pry using `gem install pry`, everything installed perfectly but typing pry in a terminal didn't work:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pry
bash: pry: command not found
```

there's a pry file in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin`.  I have to call it with ruby_noexec_wrapper in the same directory:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/pry
/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
pi@raspberrypi ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin $ ./ruby_noexec_wrapper pry
[1] pry(main)>
```

What's the proper way to run pry in this Linux?  On Windows and Mac OS X I can simply type pry at any command prompt or terminal.

***UPDATE***: Here's my `rvm info`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin $ rvm info

ruby-1.9.3-p194:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.14.10 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 day 23 hours 36 minutes 30 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "armv6l-linux-eabi"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [armv6l-linux-eabi]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: please add `rvm info`, your environment settings can be messed by "something"

Comment: Just added the `rvm info`, thanks mpapis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make sure rvm is loaded properly:

```
type rvm | head -n 1 # should be: rvm is a function
type gem | head -n 1 # should be: gem is a function
```

if they are not functions this means RVM is not properly loaded, this could be a bug in your shell (like limited bash), you can try to fix it with:

```
rvm get head --auto
```

It might be required to relogin after this command to run all shell configuration files.

next, make sure you use rvm:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
echo $PATH
echo $GEM_PATH # those two need match those from `rvm info`
rvm info
```

you can also set one ruby to be default:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

refreshing PATH - type in terminal

```
hash -r # OR:
PATH="$PATH"
```

or even relogin should help for this.

Comment: `hash -r`, restarting terminal, even rebooting the whole computer doesn't help. The result of running `type gem` in the terminal is: `gem is /home/pi/.rvm/bin/gem`. The result of running `uname -a` is: `Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux`. You mentioned the wrapper is in my PATH. Yes for the path output when running `rvm info`. However, the path when I run `echo $PATH` is: `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.rvm/bin`

Comment: Thanks mpapis. Like I wrote before, `type rvm` just gives me back the response `gem is /home/pi/.rvm/bin/gem`, it doesn't tell me `rvm is a function`. And `echo $PATH` doesn't match what's in `rvm info`.  What's the proper way to fix rvm in Debian Linux for ARM?

Comment: oh man, I rebooted the Pi and pry no longer works... so I just tried `bash -l` and pry works again.  So I guess I need to be in a login shell for RVM to work properly?

Comment: yes login shell is run when you "login", it might have different meanings depending on the context, but if you use ssh - this should be the case, what is your shell in /etc/passed - it has to be bash or zsh

Comment: I just double-click on LXTerminal when my Raspberry Pi boots up into X.  The line in my /etc/passwd file for pi is: `pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash`

Comment: you need to modify invocation of lxterminal to incude -l => http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/lxterminal.1.html

Comment: Seems like I need to add the `-l` option to lxterminal.  There's an lxterminal.desktop file which seems to represent the icon.  I can edit that file and there's a line `Exec=lxterminal`.  If I add ` -l` at the end of that line then I get a colorless shell where the prompt is simply `$` and pry still doesn't work: `sh: 1: pry: not found`.  I tried putting quotes around lxterminal on that exec line and then I just get an error when running LXTerminal.  How do I get a terminal to load and be able to run gems like pry?

Comment: this is separate question, please open a new one